# How can I keep only outer table border and remove all other borders inside the table in iText in java

Tags: java, itext

I am new to iText.
I have to create a table. I have to keep only outer border of the table. Remove all the line inside the table. Can please anyone suggest what to use. How much I have searched we can change borders of cells. But I want something which will work for whole table. Adding it to each cell one by one will be tedious job.
I have shared a sample image of what I want.
[image: Sample of table]

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [documentation on the official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/), more specifically the answer to the following questions:

- [What is the PdfPTable.DefaultCell property used for?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/what-pdfptabledefaultcell-property-used) to learn about the default cell functionality.
- [How to draw a borderless table in iTextSharp?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-draw-borderless-table-itextsharp) to learn how to use the default cell functionality to remove the borders from a table.
- [How to use a dotted line as a cell border?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-use-dotted-line-cell-border) to learn how to use table events to add custom borders.

Once you have studied the documentation, combine what you've learned into an example such as the [TableBorder](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/table-and-cell-events-draw-borders#1623-tableborder.java) example:

This creates a table without any borders:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
for(int aw = 0; aw < 16; aw++){
    table.addCell("hi");
}
document.add(table);
```

We add a table border by inserting this line:

```
table.setTableEvent(new BorderEvent());
```

The `BorderEvent` class looks like this:

```
public class BorderEvent implements PdfPTableEvent {
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths,
    float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart,
    PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        float width[] = widths[0];
        float x1 = width[0];
        float x2 = width[width.length - 1];
        float y1 = heights[0];
        float y2 = heights[heights.length - 1];
        PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        cb.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        cb.stroke();
        cb.resetRGBColorStroke();
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

**Caveat:** if this example doesn't work, please read the answer to [Why doesn't getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER) have any effect?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-doesnt-getdefaultcellsetborderpdfpcellnoborder-have-any-effect)

Somebody (me) has spent many days (even months) creating this web site with all those questions and answers. People who respect my work, use that web site to learn about iText. Other people just demand "Give me an example." The people who demand and get an example get money for work I did in their place. The people who learned about iText from my web site, get money for the work they did *and* they gain knowledge. You could say that the people who are only interested in getting the example get *money*; whereas the people who also gain knowledge, get *rich*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm late but I found a simple solution that made me achieved the goal using iTextSharp.
To get a table with border around but no on cells you can do it by following this steps:

1. Initialize a new PdfPTable with 1 column that will work as an auxiliar table;
2. Initilize a PdpCell
3. Initilize your main table and add it to the cell created before;
4. Add border to the cells of the the first table you created (the aux one).
5. Add the cell to you aux table and you will get the result.

An example of the code can be this:

```
        PdfPTable tableAux = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell auxCell = new PdfPCell();
        auxCell.AddElement(myMainTable);
        tableAux.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.RECTANGLE;
        tableAux.DefaultCell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
        tableAux.AddCell(auxCell);
```

I made it using c# but of course you can adapt the logic to your needs using java.
Best regards!

Comment: Great solution, thank you! I just had to set the total width of tableAux equal to the total width of myMainTable, and also set the width percentage of myMainTable (which defaulted to 80 in my case) to 100.